# Get last element in arraylist

Tags: java, random, arraylist

In the below code, it calls an element exactly once. How can i make it print out "this is the last element in the arraylist" when everything has been removed, and there is only one element remaining.

```
ArrayList<String> Responselist = new ArrayList<String>();
Responselist.add(CommentResponse());
Responselist.add(TriviaResponse());
Responselist.add(CriticResponse());
String[] SelectRand = new String [3];

for (int i = 0; i < SelectRand.length; ++i)
{
    int rnd = (int) (Math.random() * Responselist.size());
    SelectRand[i] = Responselist.get(rnd);
    Responselist.remove(rnd);
}

for (String x : SelectRand)
{
    if (!(Responselist.isEmpty()))
    {
        System.out.println(x);
    }
}
```

Comment: get(0)? ... Is that a real question ?

Comment: It is usually the convention in java - that non static fields and local variables identifiers start with a lower case letter. Try to follow this convention, it will make your code more readable for fellow java coders.

Comment: I actually think this was cool, the question itself is a bug finding competition. I found 4 problems (see below); but I am sure there are many more :).

Answer (score 6):

You can make a control on the size of the arraylist, id est

```
if (arraylist.size()==1){
    System.out.println("this is the last element in the arraylist");
}
```

and if you want to print the last element you can access it as (index=0 in case it is just one element)

```
arraylist.get(arraylist.size()-1);
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do it I guess:

```
if (list.size() == 1) {
  System.out.println(list.get(list.size() - 1)) // or just .get(0) of course...
} else {
  System.out.println("List is empty or bigger than one")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can resolve this with the following if-construct

```
if(responseList.size() == 1)
{
System.out.println("this is the last element in the arraylist")
}
```

You should start the variable with a lower case.

Answer (score -2):

Try and stick to conventions in java

instead of

```
ArrayList<String> Responselist = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Then code to an interface rather than a concrete class.

```
List<String> Responselist = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Also by standard java variables are camel case so it would be

```
List<String> responselist = new ArrayList<String>();
```

I think the other asnswer are sufficient to answer you original query.